# How many non-partisan (independent) legislature members were in the USA compared to the USSR?

Tags: united-states, cold-war, ussr

How many legislature members there were who were not members of any party in the USA compared to the USSR during the Cold War and now?

Comment: Isn't the answer for the USSR by definition "0"?  The legislature was elected by non-competitive elections. I can't find any evidence that membership in the communist party was a requirement to stand for election, but everything I know about the USSR indicates that there was no need to clarify that because it was obvious to all concerned.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace Russian Wikipedia claims that in the Supreme Council of the USSR of 1937 below 1/5 of the members were non-partisan, in the Supreme Council of 1970 54% of the members were independent.

Comment: IMO this is a question with potential, but it should narrow down should count a legislature on both sides (e.g. for U.S., just two houses of congress or also state legislatures).

Comment: I'm not aware of ANY member "of no party" in US Congress in practice (all the "independent" BS aside, since all of the putatively "independent" members are ex-members of some party and caucus and vote with one party majority of the time, making their "independence" a mere technicality).

Comment: On a tangent, this ought to be migrated to Politics.SE

Comment: @Anixx - being "not a partisan" != "not being a member of KPSS". Not every citizen of USSR was required (nor was) a KPSS member. But no citizen - never mind elected member of Sovet - would think/act/talk contrary to KPSS party line if they knew what was good for them. A more interesting historical question would be a simpler "were you allowed to be elected to Supreme Soviet if not a member of KPSS", IMHO.

Comment: @DVK yes I am interested in "technically" independent candidates, no matter how they vote in practice.

Comment: @Anixx - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_(politician)#Congress

Comment: I'm very skeptical that the Russian Wikipedia article means the same thing by "non-partisan" as I do.  For example, those delegates chosen as members of labor unions or nationalities might technically be "non-partisan", but I'm willing to bet that they were KPSS members.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace no, the Wikipedia says they were not KPSS members (беспартийные, party-less).

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace Into the Councils in 1980 were elected 2274699 deputies, of which there were 979805 members of the Communist party, or 43,1 percent. http://www.situation.ru/app/rs/lib/ussr100/ussr1006.htm#hdr_13 This is from official booklet issued in 1980 for foreigners visiting the USSR for the Olympics in Moscow.

Comment: @Anixx just because they weren't representing the CPSU doesn't mean they weren't required to agree with its agenda. Anyone who wasn't "loyal to the revolution" was simply not allowed to run for office (and that meant loyal to the party). There were indeed several parties in the Soviet parliament (which was mostly a hollow shell with no authority whatsoever anyway) but none that weren't vetted and under control of the CPSU. That leaves the answer to the question as: USA: x (where x is any number >= 0 yet no larger than the total number of members), USSR: 0.

Comment: @jwenting what parties do you mean? I know only one. Also the supreme council had the highest authority, for example it could adopt legislation by simple majority and did not require a president or anybody else to sign it.

Comment: @Anixx there were other parties, but they were utterly insignificant. Don't remember names, but they did exist. Effectively they were probably subsidiaries of the CPSU, but to keep up the appearance of the USSR being democratic some "opposition parties" had to be there at least on paper.

Comment: Perhaps @jwenting meant East Germany or other satellite countries where there was indeed the practice of keeping a few puppet parties, besides the KP of Wherever.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg Germany or China or North Korea...

Comment: nope, they existed in the USSR as well...

Comment: @jwenting of course, not.

Comment: @jwenting: Anixx is right on this score. Unless you count the very last elections (in 1990 IFIRC).

Comment: This question is being locked because of the excessive number of comments. If you guys want to have a discussion, take it to the chat room. I have also deleted some of the more volatile comments that had devolved into personal attacks. Future comments of that nature will result in the individuals being blocked or accounts suspended.

Answer (score 6):

For the USA, I guess the information is reasonably googlable. But as for the USSR, I wish to point out that the answer is: 0, both substantively and formally.

(1) Substantively: Clearly, no one who was really opposed to the CPSU was allowed to come within a shout of any political office.

(2) Formally: The "independent" candidates were actually running as part of a "Communist and Party-less Bloc" (which pretty much covers all bases). So even if they were not card-carrying members of the CPSU they were elected to the Supreme Soviet on behalf of the CPSU. I couldn't find an English reference to the bloc, but here is a [Russian one](http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%91%D0%A1%D0%AD/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/) from the Big Soviet Encyclopedia itself.

EDIT: Here is a contemporary reference to the bloc: http://ufn.ru/ru/articles/1937/8/b/.

EDIT: The second source I gave is a contemporary, 1937, official propaganda press release about the elections. Curiously, it was published in a physics journal (and presumably, in other journals as well). The following passage is telling:

> Быть депутатом Верховного Совета первого в мире социалистического
>   государства , состоять в железной когорте партийных и непартийных
>   большевиков , коим доверено руководство могучей , непобедимой
>   социалистической державой , — почетное и ответственное дело .
>   Величайшую ответственность перед народом , перед своими избирателями
>   должен всегда чувствовать каждый депутат.

In English (my translation):

> To be a member of the Supreme Council of the world's first socialist
>   state, to be part of the iron cohort of Party and non-Party
>   Bolsheviks, to whom entrusted the leadership of a powerful and invincible
>   socialist power - is a matter of honor and responsibility. Every deputy should always 
>   feel a great responsibility to his electors.

So, the deputies formed an "iron cohort of Party and non-Party Bolsheviks". I think it proves beyond any doubt that the "independents" were just as beholden to the party as the formally party men.

UPDATE: I found a 1947 [election poster](http://www.davno.ru/posters/%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85.html) for the "bloc".

UPDATE: More evidence: a [booklet](http://books.google.ie/books/about/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BD.html?id=ykM1AAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y), published in 1954, titled "The Indestructible Bloc of the Communists and the Party-less". Published by the State Press for Political Literature.

Comment: I'd like to see more outside evidence also for this answer. I have no sympathies for the former USSR, but could still imagine that they reserved some (token) seats for representatives of certain minorities or certain sports celebrities, say. Also, the question seems to define "independence" merely as "not member of any party", which is (much) weaker than "really opposed to the CPSU". "Formally" independent candidates would also count by that definition (or "definition" :) BTW, I recently came across [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanislav_Petrov) deserving USSR biography.

Comment: If the USA information is googlable, I see no reason why not to include it here for comparison. I also interested to know why do you assert that the US independent candidates were independent substantively. Also my question was about party members, not members of particular blocks (because party members are subjects to party discipline).

Comment: Also can you please give a source that such "Communist and party-less Bloc" existed formally rather than being just a propaganda thing.

Comment: @Anixx: Did you look up the link I gave? To the BSE? Anyway, I added another one.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg any proof that the "bloc" was formal rather than propaganda?

Comment: @Anixx: I do not understand the question. What is the distinction between "formal" and "propaganda" in your usage here? I posit that the independent members were formally tied to the party, just as strongly as the card-carrying ones. The bloc is proof positive of that, and its existence was proudly advertised by the party itself. Which part of my exposition do you take exception to?

Comment: @Drux: I added some evidence. Do you find it more convincing now?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg yes, I think that's fine. Now, the question should be improved next :) BTW, the election poster looks 1960-ish to me.

Comment: @jwenting: This may well be so, but I still think the question has an answer - which I endeavoured to give. Presumably, it is indeed not what the OP had in mind when asking.

Comment: @Anixx - if you want USA info, I linked to relevant Google article in the comment to your question. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_(politician)#Congress

Comment: @Anixx - the block wasn't formal. It didn't make it less real.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg I mean in the East Germany or N Korea there was a formal organization like "Popular front" that included the main party and some others. In the USSR there was no such thing - when a candidate was nominated by another organization, the Communists would retract their own candidate. This was called "block". You in the answer say there was a formal block.

Comment: @Anixx: okay, I see the distinction you are making. But it doesn't invalidate my basic point: that *all* candidates were put up by the party. As to your claim that the party could retract a candidate, please cite one such instance.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg this deserves opening a new question.

Comment: @downvoter: can you perhaps explain why you didn't like about my answer?

Comment: @Anixx: Actually, come to think of it, I think my claim is valid with no qualification or modification. I claimed the existence of an *electoral* bloc and, imho, have proved its existence beyond any trace of doubt. The non-existence of a popular front doesn't matter in this regard.